# resizing images, flipping immages using animation in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I am working on some animation in which there are four images. I want to do as follows:

- Flip them from right to center
- Then from center to left side

The right side should be smaller and when flipped, it should come to center and size of the image should be enlarged.

The next image should come to the center and the current image should go to left side and the size of the image should decrease by animation(or scaled).

Basically I want images to grow from right to center and then shrink to left side...same thing for left to right.
Can anybody please tell how to do this animation?
Thanks

Comment: It is difficult to follow what you mean with your animation when it's written like this, use a list?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [`android-3d-flip-view-transition`](http://code.google.com/p/android-3d-flip-view-transition/) is what you are looking for? There is also the [FlipAnimator](http://code.google.com/p/myandroidwidgets/source/browse/trunk/FlipAnimatorExample/src/com/beanie/examples/animation/FlipAnimator/FlipAnimator.java) class, it really depends on how you want to implement this but from what I can tell they both allow you to specify pivotal points so you can flip left-to-right like a book or centered like in iOS when you click the little "i" info button at the bottom-right hand corner of some apps.